# Find closures in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I have many exercises about finding the closures of different sets.

For example: *Find the closure in $C[-1/2,1]$ of the vector space generated by the functions $ [e^{kx^2};k\in \mathbb N ]$*

I would like to know the idea of the solution of this kind of exercises.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a general recipe.

Here you can note that all your functions are even, so linear combinations and limits will also be even. If you focus on the $[0,1]$ part, you can show that your functions separate points (take logarithms, note that numbers are positive). Since the span is an algebra, by Stone Weierstrass you get all of $C[0,1]$. So the closure is
$$
\{t\longmapsto f(|t|):\ f\in C[0,1]\}. 
$$

Comment: For Stone-Weierstraß one also needs to remark that the thing is an algebra, which is true here since $e^{kx^2}\cdot e^{lx^2}= e^{(k+l)x^2}$.

Comment: Indeed. In my mind, everything's an algebra :D

Comment: Everything is an algebra if you try hard enough!

Comment: So true. We can always go for the zero product, after all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But, what will be the difference if we are asked to find the closure in $C[0,1]$?

Comment: As a set, it is the same. What is different in your question is that all functions that generate your space satisfy $f(t)=f(-t)$; that doesn't show in $C[0,1]$. Or, to put it in another way, your subspace is dense in $C[0,1]$.